# Objects creation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a dataset which return me a set of tuples in this format `(region, district, city, role)`, and I want to create a hierarchy, but the loop doesn't work in correct way, it creates only `region` objects and also duplicates this objects 
entry:

```
('Рівненська обл.', 'Дубенський р-н', 'с.Нова Миколаївка', Place.VILLAGE)
 ('Тернопільська обл.', 'Чортківський р-н', 'с.Мухавка', Place.VILLAGE)
 ('Житомирська обл.', 'Попільнянський р-н', 'с.Миролюбівка', Place.VILLAGE)
 ('Тернопільська обл.', 'Бучацький р-н', 'с.Передмістя', Place.VILLAGE)
 ('Дніпропетровська обл.', 'Царичанський р-н', 'с.Рибалки', Place.VILLAGE)
```

my model:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Place name', )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):

    help = 'Fill DB with initial data'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for entry in list(get_dataset())[:10]:
            region, region_created = Place.objects.get_or_create(name=entry[0], role=Place.REGION)
            district, district_created = Place.objects.get_or_create(name=entry[1], role=Place.DISTRICT, parent=region)
            city_obj, city_created = Place.objects.get_or_create(name=entry[2], role=entry[3], parent=district)

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Database updated successfully!'))
```

Comment: What exactly happens with the rest? Can you share relevant parts of your `Place` model? What if a city has a district that has the same name as the city?

Comment: please, show few example of your `entry`.

Comment: @Bear Brown ok, no problem

Comment: if i understand correct, you can add the `unique_together = ['name', 'parent']`? may be need clear table before it, and after apply the constraint you should catch a error that can help you.